# Mock 'ora' with Jest to see if it was called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I'm using jest and trying to Mock the `ora` package's `spinner.start` to see if it was called. I was trying the following as I think they have done it in another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55437111/mock-node-external-module-default-with-chained-method-using-jest)

My code (lala.js):

```
import ora from 'ora';
const spinner = ora({ indent: 2 });


export const lala = () => {
  spinner.start('dfsdfsdf');
  return 'hey';
};


export default lala();
```

test file:

```
import { lala } from './lala';
import ora from 'ora';

jest.mock('ora', () => () => {
  const start = jest.fn();
  const result = { start };
  return result;
});

describe('lala', () => {
  it.only('calls start', () => {
    lala();
    const spinner = ora();
    expect(spinner.start).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

The error i'm getting from Jest is that it wasn't called as show in the following code block:

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

Expected number of calls: >= 1
Received number of calls:    0
```

I have tried so many things and importing/mocking this many ways but can't seem to get it to work. Eventually, I want to do `toHaveBeenCalledWith('dfsdfsdf')` but I can't even mock this correctly yet. Any help would be appreciated. I am using the following versions of Jest and Ora:

`"jest": "24.8.0",`
`"ora": "3.2.0",`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get a working solution. I solved this by creating a helper function which initialises the ora object and is used in `lala.js`.

```
import ora from 'ora';
export const spinner = ora({ indent: 2 });
```

that way I can import the object in my test file and spy on `start` and then use the spy in my expectation like so:

```
import { spinner } from './utils/ora-helper';

export const lala = () => {
  spinner.start('dfsdfsdf');
  return 'hey';
};

export default lala();
```

```
import { lala } from './lala';
import { spinner } from './utils/ora-helper';

describe('lala', () => {
  it.only('calls start', () => {
    const spinnerSpy = jest.spyOn(spinner, 'start');
    lala();

    expect(spinnerSpy).toHaveBeenCalled(); // works like a charm
  });
});
```